# utm_source and utm_medium gets lost in SPA

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, single-page-application, google-tag-manager

I've got a weird problem with my SPA application and analytics. The source/medium parameters are being lost during the session for some users.

I'm using the history API using Google Tag Manager as recommended, and it works. But for approximate 30% of the users loose their utm parameters and becomes referrals. I don't understand this behaviour, anyone seen this before?

So, I know that 100% are

```
(source/medium) = mySource / affiliate
```

but looking in analytics, approximately 30% are loosing their utm parameters and it becomes:

```
(source/medium) = mySource / affiliate (70%)
(source/medium) = mysource.com / referral (30%)
```

Any suggestions? I'm a bit lost right now.

Answer (score 1):

As the sites is a Single Page Application (SPA), you are most likely facing the problem of 'Rogue Referral'.

If this is the case, what happens, is that you overwrite the `location` field in the Analytics hit, losing the original UTM parameters, whereas referral is still sent with the hit, so Analytics recognizes the second hit as a new traffic source. One of the solutions is to store the original page URL and send it as the `location`, while sending the actual visited URL in the `page` field.

A very good [article](https://www.simoahava.com/gtm-tips/fix-rogue-referral-problem-single-page-sites/) on this topic with further tips, by Simo Ahava, is available for your help.

Comment: Yes, thank you kgrg. I did indeed base a lot of my programming on that article, so I do indeed keep the source/medium now. But that doesn't explain why it dissapears every other link-click. It's really weird.

Comment: You could identify these users in the User explorer reports, and check if there's a specific page or event, that forces them to start a new session. (Maybe there's a specific tag, that behaves differently.)

Comment: Yes, I have done that too! :-) It shows that every other interaction, the source/medium dissapears/reappears. It's a really annoying behaviour and right now I'm more into looking how GA's code works..

Answer (score 1):

This [article](https://www.simoahava.com/gtm-tips/fix-rogue-referral-problem-single-page-sites/) regarding the "rogue referral" problem exposes a solution which only works for Google Tag Manager, and also if you follow the article you would be sending the same page location for the whole application (if I understand correctly), which is something we didn't want.

Besides, it doesn't take into account some filtering of the parameter (sending the parameters only if useful ones are present), so we have come up with this solution.

Please note that the code needs to run at the first load of the page and at every route change.

### Function to retrieve the parameters

```js
// return the whole parameters only if at least one of the desired parameters exists
const retrieveParams = () => {
  let storedParams;
  if ('URLSearchParams' in window) {
    // Browser supports URLSearchParams
    const url = new URL(window.location.href);
    const params = new URLSearchParams(url.search);
    const requestedParams = ['utm_source', 'utm_medium', 'utm_campaign', 'utm_content', 'gclid'];
    const hasRequestedParams = requestedParams.some((param) => {
      // true if it exists
      return !!params.get(param);
    });
    if (hasRequestedParams) {
      storedParams = params;
    }
  }
  return storedParams;
}
```

#### Create the full URL

```js
// look at existing parameters (from previous page navigations) or retrieve new ones
const storedParams = window.storedParams || retrieveParams();
let storedParamsUrl;
if (storedParams) {
  // update window value
  window.storedParams = storedParams;
  // create the url
  const urlWithoutParams = document.location.protocol + '//' + document.location.hostname + document.location.pathname;
  storedParamsUrl = `${urlWithoutParams}?${storedParams}`;
}
```

#### Send the value to analytics (using gtag)

```js
// gtag
gtag('config', 'YOUR_GA_ID', {
  // ... other parameters
  page_location: storedParamsUrl ?? window.location.href
});
```

or

```js
gtag('event', 'page_view', {
  // ... other parameters
  page_location: storedParamsUrl ?? window.location.href,
  send_to: 'YOUR_GA_ID'
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is (probably) referrer. When user comes to a site (with utm's in url) it has referrer for example xyz.com when it makes a click on a site SPA does not reload the page, meaning referrer will still be xyz.com BUT url does not include utm's now

So the case is that for google such second page-view is a new session. To solve it you need to work on referrer wich on the first page-view (real page load) will provide proper referrer, and on all other hits it will provide null or domain as a referrer :)

Details:
https://dronsom.com/2021/06/11/single-page-application-proper-pageview-measurement-solving-issue-with-google-and-referrer-traffic