# Google analytics splits sessions on single page application (Rogue Referral Problem)

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, single-page-application, google-tag-manager, gatsby

We are using `gatsby` to develop our website and I am using the `gatsby-plugin-google-tagmanager` plugin in order to fire `google analytic events`..

One issue we face is that when the user visits our site from `utm` links the `session` seems to split the exact same second he lands on the page.

**What I do so far**

Fire a `Page View` `Google Analytics: Universal Analytics` tag using the `gatsby-route-change` trigger.

**GA debug report**

One thing that seems abnormal is that on every route change, using the `GA Debug` tool,  a new `Creating new tracker` log is created.

[image]

**Ways I tried to fix this**

Read an article that on single page applications you might get faulty values for `page`, `location` and `referrer` properties, so this fools google analytics to create a new session each time, so that might be the reason why the session breaks.

What I tried to do was to override these values in the GA tag. However, this does not seem to fix the issue.

```
// Location override gtm variable
function () {
    return window.document.location.protocol + '//' +
      window.document.location.hostname +
      window.document.location.pathname +
      window.document.location.search
}

// Referrer override gtm variable
function () {
    return window.history.state.referrer
}

// Page override gtm variable
function() {
  var path = window.location.pathname + window.location.search + window.location.hash
  var index = path.indexOf('?');
  if(index > -1){
     path = path.substring(0, index);
  }
  return path;
}
```

Got any idea on this? Is it possible that this behavior splits our session? Is there anything else you recommend?

Comment: Can you share the utm strings and an example of two URLs where the sessions split?

Comment: @Jesse any utm value does the same.. eg ?utm_source=test&utm_medium=testmedium.

Comment: That’s true, can you share an example of the two URLs where this issue occurs?

Comment: this is the default behaviour for Google Analytics. Once GA receives pageview hit with UTM parameters it starts a new session for the consequent hits. https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/6205762?hl=en

Comment: @ДмитроБулах Yes that is the default behaviour, but the issue I have is that the session is dropped so you then lose the utm params.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this in Gatsby?  I'm stumped!

Comment: @beamercola You can find the solution below. The article explains it in detail, however, ping me if you need any help.

Comment: @itdoesntwork I think I'm just confused on where to put this code.  Just in a script tag in head?  the "script variable" is super confusing to me I've never seen anything like that.  Appreciate the help!

Comment: @beamercola well this question is about google tag manager. if you don't use gtm you probably have a different issue. "script variable" is a gtm variable.

Comment: @cYberSport91 Here is my solution that I've used in Gatsby: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67437006/. I think you can use the code in `gatsby-browser.js` in the onRouteUpdate function

Comment: Does this answer your question? [utm\_source and utm\_medium gets lost in SPA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55848962/utm-source-and-utm-medium-gets-lost-in-spa)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://www.simoahava.com/gtm-tips/fix-rogue-referral-problem-single-page-sites/

This article answers the question.

> With Google Tag Manager, every single Universal Analytics Tag that fires on the site creates a new, unique tracker object. This means that the Document Location field is updated with every Tag you fire, which is a problem if the URL changes due to browser history manipulation. Thus you can end up with a situation where the first Universal Analytics Tag has gclid in the URL, attributing the session to AdWords, but the next pageview doesn’t have this in the URL anymore, as you would not include it in the “virtual” pageview path names. Instead, since gclid is no longer in the URL, GA looks at the HTTP referrer of the page to see what the previous page was for attribution. It finds google.com, as you came from the search engine (HTTP referrer is not updated when manipulating the URL with the browser History API). Thus a new session starts with attribution to Google Organic! I’ve dubbed this as the Rogue Referral problem.

**Solution**

Manually Set Document Location To Prevent Rogue Referrals

1. Create a script to save the landing URL in the dataLayer

   ```
   window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
   window.dataLayer.push({
   originalLocation: document.location.protocol + '//' +
                   document.location.hostname +
                   document.location.pathname +
                   document.location.search
   });
   ```
2. Create a script variable to get the current page. (if you don't need hash remove it)

   ```
   function() {
     return window.location.pathname + window.location.search + 
       window.location.hash
   }
   ```

Add variables to all you Universal Analytics by manually setting the fields location and page

[image]