# Setting up Goals in Google Analytics for a Single Page Application

Tags: google-analytics, single-page-application, google-tag-manager

While setting up goals in single page application in google analytics through gtm there was a problem with achieving 'pageview' goals from `CPC` source, although when I was looking at the current page in real-time I saw page is active, so the goal should be achieved but it doesn't.

Is anybody faced with such behavior of google analytics?

Comment: You don't need GTM to create a goal for page view. Did you create a goal in GA?

Comment: Sure, i have made a few pageview goals in google analytics but they are achieving only as direct traffic

Comment: Could you show screen shot of goal settings?

Comment: There are screenshots of test goals settings:
https://prnt.sc/q8dgaa
https://prnt.sc/q8dh4q

But there is nothing extraordinary in it

Comment: You say about SPA, but use as a goal URL destination. Is page in screenshot a homepage? Or virtual page?

Comment: I made a virtual "pageview"

Comment: Are you sure that page path of virtual page doesn't contain hostname? ('/connectors' but not 'www.domain.com/connectors')

Comment: I've posted an answer to this problem here https://stackoverflow.com/a/67437006/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [utm\_source and utm\_medium gets lost in SPA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55848962/utm-source-and-utm-medium-gets-lost-in-spa)

Answer (score 0):

Probably when the URL of your single-page changes it loses the *gclic* parameter but the referral is always *google*, so your session is interrupted and a new one starts from the organic channel to which the rest of the pages viewed are associated.

Try to read this article:
https://www.simoahava.com/gtm-tips/fix-rogue-referral-problem-single-page-sites/

Comment: Thanks, I will try the approach which was offered in this article and report the results

Comment: Ok, let me know!