# GA hits a new session by clicking on a button tracked with a GA Event

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I created different Google Analytics tags (one pageview on all pages) and track event on some buttons with Google Tag Manager. When I'm analyzing the Google Analytics details by recording a session with Tag Assistant, I noticed the a **new session** is surprisingly starting when I'm clicking on a button on a page different than the landing page.

Ex.: Click on a Google Ads

Session 1:

1. Hit type = pageview (landing page) (trigger based on dataLayer event - the website is asynchronously loaded - single page website)

   > AdWords Click ID: xxx /Source, Medium, Name: (not set)
2. Click on a link: hit type = event

   > AdWords Click ID: xxx /Source, Medium, Name: (not set)
3. Hit type = pageview (other page)

   > AdWords Click ID: xxx /Source, Medium, Name: (not set)

Session 2:

4. Click on a second link: hit type = event

   > a new session is starting with the following information:
   >   Source : Google.com, Medium : referral (instead of AdWords Click ID: xxx /Source, Medium, Name: (not set))

All the tags have the same setup, and surprisingly, if I'm landing on the second page from a Google ads, Google Analytics is not creating a new session. This issue is always occurring when I'm clicking on a tracked button on other page different than the landing page. If I'm coming from natural search or another campaign tracked with utm, Google Analytics doesn't create a new session. It's look like the Gclid data is not well passed through the website and more especially on track event button on other pages different than the landing page.

Has anybody already encountered this issue?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I have posted an answer to a similar problem here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67437006/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [utm\_source and utm\_medium gets lost in SPA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55848962/utm-source-and-utm-medium-gets-lost-in-spa)

Answer (score 0):

Probably your site is a single-page-site or the URL is updated dynamically without refresh the page. During navigation you lose the gclid parameter but the referral remains the same (google.com), so the first session is *google /cpc* and the second generated becomes *google / organic*.

Try this tutorial to fix the problem:

https://www.simoahava.com/gtm-tips/fix-rogue-referral-problem-single-page-sites/