# Purchase event fires with no page view on UTM tracked sessions

Tags: events, google-analytics, single-page-application, pageviews, enhanced-ecommerce

we have a single page application site and have had some difficulties with pageview tracking, which has now been resolved.

However, we're seeing that when a Google Analytics purchase event fires during the checkout process, the session breaks (being broken by the event) and then the event will be attributed to organic rather than paid (screenshot included). This is also occurring on UTM tracked referral links too.

Has anyone encountered this before? As it's preventing automated Shopping campaigns from learning from conversion data.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RYiln.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [utm\_source and utm\_medium gets lost in SPA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55848962/utm-source-and-utm-medium-gets-lost-in-spa)

Answer (score 0):

This happens because the sending of subsequent pages in a Single Page Application takes place (rightly) without the parameter (i.e. `gclid` or `UTMs`) but, since the `referrer` always remains Google, what was Paid traffic subsequently interrupts the session and generates a new one from organic.

Try to check this article to **Fix The Rogue Referral Problem In Single-Page Sites**: https://www.simoahava.com/gtm-tips/fix-rogue-referral-problem-single-page-sites/

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention, original location has been added as a datalayer to the site and this has been set in our GA tag too

Comment: Probably it lost parameter(s) when send hits in checkout process, maintaining same referrer. You have to debug that part.